# Prime divisors of $p^n-1$, primitive prime divisors

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p,q,t_1,t_2$ be distinct prime numbers and let
$$k=\frac{p^{qt_1t_2}-1}{p^q-1}.$$
Suppose that $\gcd(k,qt_1t_2)=1$. Is there any reason that $k$ is divisible by at least $7$ distinct prime numbers?

Using Zsigmondy's theorem, one can show that $k$ is divisible by at least $6$ distinct primes. But I do not have any example where $6$ is achieved. Actually, $t_1=3$, $t_2=5$, $p=2$, $q=13$ is the only example that I have with $k$ divisible by only $7$ distinct primes.

Comment: Should your last sentence be "… $k$ divisible by *only* $7$ distinct primes"?

Comment: Thanks I have corrected it with your suggestion.

Comment: Other examples are given by $p=3$, $q t_1 t_2 = 70$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each of the seven divisors $d$ of $qt_1t_2$ different from $q$, let $r_d$ be a prime divisor of $\Phi_d(p)$, where $\Phi_d$ is the $d$-th cyclotomic polynomial. The assumption $\text{gcd}(k,qt_1t_2)=1$ and $k=\prod_{d}\Phi_d(p)$ guarantees that $r_d$ does not divide $d$. So $r_d$ has order $d$ modulo $p$. In particular, the seven $r_d$'s are distinct.

The fact that $\Phi_d(p)$ actually has a prime divisor (that is $\Phi_d(p)\ne\pm1$) is a special case of an argument in the proof of Zsigmondy's theorem.

*Remark*: The case $p=2$ needs an enhanced argument.

Comment: "The case $p = 2$ needs an enhanced argument" is pretty much the story of mathematics involving a prime parameter, isn't it? 

Comment: Thanks Peter. Now that I see that, it is natural I wasn't thinking about considering the prime for $d=1$. But, did you have an idea what do to in the case $p=2$?

Comment: @PabloSpiga $p=2$ probably is hopeless. In a counterexample, $\Phi_d(2)$ would have to be a prime power for each divisor $d$ of $qt_1t_2$ except for $1$ and $q$. In particular, $2^{t_i}-1$ would be Mersenne primes. There are examples which come close: For $t_1, t_2, q=3, 5, 149$, $\Phi_d(2)$ is a prime for all $d\in\{t_1, t_2, t_1t_2, qt_1, qt_2\}$, it only fails for $d=qt_1t_2$.